# Visual bug when displayheadings = false

Tags: excel, vba

As the title says, I experience visual bugs when and only when

```
ActiveWindow.DisplayHeadings = False
```

Here is an image of the type of bug I receive (the masterfully blued-out info is due to confidential work information, don't mind it). It happens when I scroll left-right:

[image: Heading on, with bug]

After refreshing (no bug):

[image: After refreshing, no bug]

Note that there is the black stripe AND the cell on the right, which was a merged cell that looks sort of cut in half? It looks like the others normally.

Selecting it makes the bug disappear in the selected region. As such, I have developped this little macro to refresh the screen. It selects to whole screen - erasing the bugs - and returns to the selected range. It works fine.

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim active As Range
Set active = ActiveCell

Cells.Select
active.Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Now, I would like to do one of two things, preferrably the first:

1) Figure out why this happens, if it only happens to me, and how to fix it.

2) Think of a way to launch my refresh macro every time the user scrolls side to side.

Additional info:

Excel 2010

Happens whether Application.EnableEvents, ScreenUpdating, etc are True or not.

Comment: Have you tried changing activeWindow to ActiveWorkbook?

Comment: As far as I know that doesn't even exist (if you're talking about ActiveWindow.Displayheadings)

Comment: my apologies it doesn't for DisplayHeadings but does exist with other functions...are you certain its that line causing the issue? can't seem to replicate the problem and never seen it before.

Comment: Why do you even have the code, isn't the active cell already selected.

Comment: @Davesexcel Yes... if you read my post you will notice the post is about a visual bug. Selecting the entire sheet removes the bug. It selects the sheet, removes the bug, and comes back to the initial selection.

Comment: @Kdean571 Yes it is caused entirely by that line. I have commented it out and problems stop immediately. Commenting it back in cause them to reappear.